# How to get converted boolean value to show as selected value in the editable drop down list in asp.net gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a database flag, ActiveFlag, that I show as Yes/No in the gridview row.  On edit, a drop down list that presents the options is displayed, however it always shows Yes even if the current value is No.  I'm sure the problem is that the code I have to show the selected item is not working, but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="ActiveFlag"
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("ActiveFlag").ToString()))? "Yes" : "No" %>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActive" runat="server" 
           Selected='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("ActiveFlag").ToString()))? "Yes" : "No" %>' >
            <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I'm still new to all of this and I'm sure its a noob-ish question, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DropDownList's [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

***Note***: Make sure conditional operator are ListItems' values. In your code, they are "1" and "0".

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlActive" runat="server"
    SelectedValue='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("ActiveFlag"))? "1" : "0" %>'>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```